# Negative Conditional Probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

> $A$ and $B$ are events with $P(A)=0.2, P(B)=0.6$ and $P(B|A)=0.9$.
>
> Find $P(B|\bar{A})$, giving answers to within $1\%$ of the exact value.

The problem is shown in the image above. I need to find P(B given not A), however I am getting an answer of -0.3 which doesn't make sense.

I am applying the following equation:

$$P(B)=P(B|A)+P(B|\bar{A})$$

Comment: The equation you linked reads $P[B] = P[B \mid A] + P[B \mid \bar{A}]$ which is not true.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help if you [edit] the question to show us the problem and your actual work, not just the equation you used.  No images please: use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4):

The Law of total probability is as follows, 
$$P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|\bar{A})P(\bar{A})$$

some terms are missing from your equations. Hence, the error.